# Add optional query parameters with default value to self link in hateoas

Tags: hateoas

One of the endpoints of the backend I'm developing accepts an optional parameter. If this parameter is not sent by the client it will take a default value. So this `GET` call

```
http://my.host.com/some_endpoint
```

is equivalent to

```
http://my.host.com/some_endpoint?some_parameter=0
```

This is the json response:

```
{
    ...
    "_links": {
        "self": "http://my.host.com/some_endpoint"
    }
}
```

In the second `GET` the `self` value has the `?some_parameter=0` at the end. Should it should be added too to the first call?

In other words: should the response of

```
GET http://my.host.com/some_endpoint
```

be

```
{
    ...
    "_links": {
        "self": "http://my.host.com/some_endpoint"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    ...
    "_links": {
        "self": "http://my.host.com/some_endpoint?some_parameter=0"
    }
}
```

On one hand, the `self` value should refer to the URL you requested but in the other hand the one with the parameter is equivalent and if you don't receive it you won't know that that option is available (unless you read the documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Hypertext Application Language](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) (HAL) [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-03) specification enforces the "href" in conformity with the "Target IRI" defined in Web Linking specification ([RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)).

> Applications that don't wish to register a relation type can use an
> extension relation type, which is a URI [RFC3986] that **uniquely**
> identifies the relation type.

So I'd say that the self value shouldn't necessarily refer to the requested URL, but rather be unique (and thus *include any unspecified optional parameters*, with their default value).